# how do i insert date from jdatepicker to mysql database am using java swing

Tags: java, mysql

I have convert java.util.date to String instead of being java.sql  and  inserting the selected Date as String, to Mysql Column with date datatype. The selected date is inserted successfull i am unable to insert it as java.sql.Date. Any one with idea with it pleasee share it with us....

Here is the Complete Code

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
//import jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.Statement;
//import static sun.misc.ClassFileTransformer.add;
   import org.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePanelImpl;
    import org.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePickerImpl;
    import org.jdatepicker.impl.UtilDateModel;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.Date.*;
    import java.util.Date;
    import javax.swing.*;

public class Testd {

    Connection con = null;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    JButton btn;
    //Date datee;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Testd();
    }

    public Testd() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setLayout(null);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            btn = new JButton("Add");
            btn.setBounds(280, 350, 200, 30);

            UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
            Properties p = new Properties();
            p.put("text.today", "Today");
            p.put("text.month", "Month");
            p.put("text.year", "Year");
            JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model, p);
            JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel, new DateLabelFormatter());
            datePicker.setBounds(220, 350, 120, 50);

            //datee = (Date) datePicker.getModel().getValue();
            //  datee=selectedDate+"";
            add(datePicker);
            add(btn);

            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    try {


                        Date datee = (Date) datePicker.getModel().getValue();
                        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        String reportDate = df.format(datee);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,reportDate);

                        if (datee != null) {
                           // java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(reportDate.getText());
                            String sql = "INSERT INTO Invoice"
                                    + "(DueDate)"
                                    + "VALUES (?)";

                           con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/Sales"+"?useSSL=false","root","8000");
                           pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                           pst.setString(1,reportDate);
                           pst.executeUpdate();

                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "You need to select a date");
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException | HeadlessException ex) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "ERROR UNABLE TO INSERT ");
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, ex);

                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public class DateLabelFormatter extends AbstractFormatter {

        private String datePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);

        @Override
        public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
            return dateFormatter.parseObject(text);
        }

        @Override
        public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
            if (value != null) {
                Calendar cal = (Calendar) value;
                return dateFormatter.format(cal.getTime());
            }

            return "";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: IF, your code is running in this direct state, then when you use `datePicker.getModel().getValue();` no value has been selected. Also, WHY are you using `datee=selectedDate+"";`?  This isn't going to return you a date in a reliable format, you should just continue to use the `Date` value itself.  This would mean that rather then jumping through the hoops of trying to reformat the date, you could just use `PreparedStatement#setDate` directly

Comment: am still having an error: incompatible types: Date cannot be converted to String
        String text = selectedDate;

Comment: Yes, because you’re taking the value from the date picker before the user has selected anything

Comment: datee=selectedDate+"";   it means datee is a variable of type String which is accessible within the contructor and within the method actionperformed

Comment: And is completely pointless and the wrong approach - what ActionListener? The date pickers? The problem is NO DATE HAS BEEN SELECTED and therefore it is NULL. If you are selecting a value, then you are shadowing your variables

Comment: okey please help me how can i get selected value and insert it to my database because am still the beginner

Comment: Post a complete, verifiable and runnable example which demonstrates your problem - this is not a code dump, but a focused example which demonstrates your workflow and the issue you’re having

Comment: okey thanks  i will post the complete code again, by now i have reached the question limit

Comment: @MadProgrammer i have post the complete code please help me....

Comment: As I stated earlier, `datee = (Date) datePicker.getModel().getValue();` needs to go in your `ActionListener`, only when `actionPerformed` will the selected value be available - you should verify that `datee` is not `null` though, as the user may still not have selected anything

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in call `datee = (Date) datePicker.getModel().getValue();` in the `TestPane` constructor, as the value has not yet been selected by the user, the date picker hasn't even been added to the panel, the panel hasn't been added to the frame and the frame hasn't been displayed on the screen.

You need to do this within the `ActionListener`'s `actionPerformed` method, but still check to see if it's `null`

The following example makes use of a [H2, in memory database](http://www.h2database.com).  This example also shows what is to be inserted and what was inserted.  Note though - this is a quirk of how H2 works, as I simply list ALL the values in the `invoice` table, but it's the last one which is displayed on the screen.  Better to use a `System.out` statement instead ;)

[image: Inserting dates]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import org.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePanelImpl;
import org.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePickerImpl;
import org.jdatepicker.impl.UtilDateModel;

public class Testd {

    JButton btn;
    //Date datee;

    private JLabel input;
    private JLabel output;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Testd();
    }

    public Testd() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                try {
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setLayout(null);
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Connection con;

        public TestPane() throws SQLException {
            make();

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            btn = new JButton("Add");

            UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
            Properties p = new Properties();
            p.put("text.today", "Today");
            p.put("text.month", "Month");
            p.put("text.year", "Year");
            JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model, p);
            JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel, new DateLabelFormatter());

            JPanel top = new JPanel();

            top.add(datePicker);
            top.add(btn);

            add(top, gbc);

            input = new JLabel("---");
            output = new JLabel("---");

            JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
            bottom.add(input);
            bottom.add(output);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            add(bottom, gbc);

            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    try {
                        // String text = datee;
                        // DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                        // Date myDate = formatter.parse(text);
                        java.util.Date datee = (java.util.Date) datePicker.getModel().getValue();
                        if (datee != null) {
                            java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(datee.getTime());

                            String sql = "INSERT INTO Invoice"
                                            + "(Issuedate)"
                                            + "VALUES (?)";

                            input.setText(sqlDate.toString());

                            try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                                stmt.setDate(1, sqlDate);
                                int rowCount = stmt.executeUpdate();
                                System.out.println(rowCount);
                                con.commit();
                            }

                            select();

                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "You need to select a date");
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException | HeadlessException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, ex);

                    }
                }
            });
        }

        protected void select() throws SQLException {
            try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from Invoice")) {
                try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        java.sql.Date date = rs.getDate(1);
                        output.setText(date.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void make() throws SQLException {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:");
            try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
                boolean result = stmt.execute("create table Invoice( Issuedate date not null )");
                System.out.println(result);
                con.commit();
                select();
            }
        }
    }

    public class DateLabelFormatter extends AbstractFormatter {

        private String datePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);

        @Override
        public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
            return dateFormatter.parseObject(text);
        }

        @Override
        public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
            if (value != null) {
                Calendar cal = (Calendar) value;
                return dateFormatter.format(cal.getTime());
            }

            return "";
        }

    }
}
```

If you continue to have issues, I would strongly recommend that you create a simple project, remove the UI and focus entirely on working with the database so you can get a better understanding of how to work with JDBC and the database

Comment: Am still getting  java.lang.NullPointerException it seems  Date datee = (Date) datePicker.getModel().getValue();  return empty value

Comment: I've run the code.  So long as you actually select a date from the picker, it works fine - which suggests, that you're not selecting a value from the picker - or some other part of your program is at fault

Comment: I`ve copy the above code but am still getting Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Testd$TestPane$1.actionPerformed(Testd.java:102)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)

Comment: If, you do not select a value from the picker, it will return null. I tested the above code, selected a date and pressed add and printed the date (I took out the database code as I didn’t need it)

Comment: I don't know what is the problem on my side  am selecting the date from jdatepicker but then when i press Add button it return null.

Comment: i hav created this as mysql table  create table Invoice(
Issuedate  date not null,
PRIMARY KEY (Issuedate)   
);

Comment: What's at line `102` (`Testd.java:102`)?

Comment: I have changed this code insteady of variable pst i have use stmt, i.e try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                                    stmt.setDate(1, sqlDate);
                                    stmt.executeUpdate();    this doesn't return null exception but incorrect date is inserted which is 1970-01-01

Comment: Sorry, I was copying and pasting in Notes on my mobile

Comment: Okay, so I've set up test using H2 database and can insert and select the correct date value from the database without issue

Comment: I've updated my example to select all the values from the database after the insert. I would, highly, recommend adding a `System.out.println` into the `while-loop` used to see what is actually been inserted into the database

Comment: I have changed my code instead of using java.sql.Date sqlDate i hav converted selected date to String and insert the value as pst.setString(1,reportDate);  But The Mysql Datatype is still date..  I dont know if i am right or not. The selected date is now inserted successfull.

Comment: Let me edit the code.... check it to see if am correct am so thanks @MadProgrammer for your support.............

Comment: I Have changed the code please check it to see if what i have changed is recommended or not. Now The selected date is inserted successfull.